# Binding not working after copying and renaming activity to new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm doing a little project to teach myself some Kotlin and Android programming using Android Studio. Up until now I've just been creating single activities in standalone apps. However, now I'd like to start adding some navigation features and start linking different activities together.

So I don't mess up my work so far, I've created a new project and given it a new name. I have manually copied across the layout (which I've renamed to activity_abdominal_exam.xml) as well as any strings, drawables and colours that I'm using.

I then created a new Empty Activity, gave it a new name (AbdominalExam) and copied the code from my original activity into AbdominalExam. I changed the `package` declaration to match the new project name and changed the `class` in the code to match the new activity name.

However, the binding isn't recognising the ids for my layout, and when I try to compile I get Unresolved reference errors for those IDs e.g. `Unresolved reference: b1`. However, if I declare a variable and use `findViewById` the code has no problem identifying and using these IDs. Can anyone help? I've copied some of the code below; please say if you need to see some other code and I'll edit the post.

---

AbdominalExam.kt (the new Empty Activity I created. Code copied from MainActivity in original project)

```
package com.example.clinicalskills

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import com.example.clinicalskills.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class AbdominalExam : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val listOfScores: MutableList <Int> = mutableListOf(0,0,0,0,0) //the scores for each button in button order
        val listOfMaxScores: List<Int> = listOf(2,1,2,1,1) //the max scores for each of the buttonss in order

        val myButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.b1)
        
        binding.b1.setOnClickListener { listOfScores[0] = buttonPress2(listOfScores[0], binding.b1) }
        binding.b2.setOnClickListener { listOfScores[1] = buttonPress1(listOfScores[1], binding.b2) }
        binding.b3.setOnClickListener { listOfScores[2] = buttonPress2(listOfScores[2], binding.b3) }
        binding.b4.setOnClickListener { listOfScores[3] = buttonPress1(listOfScores[3], binding.b4) }
        binding.b5.setOnClickListener { listOfScores[4] = buttonPress1(listOfScores[4], binding.b5) }

        binding.score.setOnClickListener { calculateScore(listOfScores, listOfMaxScores) }
    }
 //code truncated - rest of code declares the functions referenced above
```

---

activity_abdominal_exam.xml - Layout file for AbdominalExam

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wipe_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/line1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_wipe"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/wipe"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/b1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/wipe_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/out_of_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/line2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/line2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bed"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/end_of_bed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/out_of_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/line2"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/line3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/line3"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_hand"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/hands"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/out_of_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/line3"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/line4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/line4"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_skin"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/skin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/out_of_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/line4"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/line5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/line5"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_pulse"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/pulse"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/line1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/line4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/grey"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/out_of_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/line5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculate_score"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your binding class is still called ``ActivityMainBinding``, but the XML file is called ``activity_abdominal_exam.xml``, which would generate a binding file called ``ActivityAbdominalExamBinding``. Also do a ``Clean`` (in the ``Build`` menu) and maybe ``Invalidate caches/restart`` under ``File`` if you need to, it cleans stuff out and remakes generated code. It can help for things like autocomplete not finding things, or stuff not being recognised

Comment: private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding   must change with  private lateinit var binding: ActivityAbdominalExamBinding and         binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) with the         binding = ActivityAbdominalExamBinding .inflate(layoutInflater)

Comment: Thanks both. I had actually tried changing ActivityAbdominalExamBinding in the importer but had forgotten to change the other references in the code. All working now.